# Perl why is this while loop not working?

Tags: perl

```
my $cmte_money_total = 0;
while ($cmte_money_total == 0){
  # body of function
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this syntax? It keeps giving me an error.

Comment: At the very least, say what error are you getting!!!

Answer (score 4):

No.

```
$ perl -c -e'
  my $cmte_money_total = 0;
  while ($cmte_money_total == 0){
    # body of function
  }
'
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with it.

The problem is somewhere else. Post complete minimal code which produces a problem.